# I have two table in database like Table1 and Table2.I have attached picture for explaination my problem

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, vue.js

[image]

I have two table like table1 and table2.which contain some data. I want to join both table together in mysql join.I need resultant table explained in picture.

Please help me to solve my problem

Thanks

I have attached image. please see this image.

Comment: Common INNER JOIN... maybe plus ORDER BY. Read about SQL .. at least something.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: see if this works "select table1.name, table2.cell_table1, table2.page from table2 inner join table1 on table2.cell_table1 = table1.cell where table1.cell = 'waseem'"

Comment: either you do join or laravel's lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query is right and you can use any programming to filter this result and convert as per the required table format

Comment: please suggest in program which i can use to achieve this.